# Windows 11 WDS unattend xml answer file not doing asynchronousCommand

Tags: wds, windows-11

I am currently trying to use WDS to deploy a windows 11 image. I want to run a powershell script after the admin logs in (prompt for the computer name) but I can't even get an mkdir to work. Am I doing something wrong? can I check logs or something on the local computer to debug what happened and what error it returns?

```
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
            <InputLocale>0813:00000813</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>nl-BE</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>nl-NL</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>nl-BE</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Name>Administrator</Name>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <Password>
                            <Value>password</Value>
                            <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <AutoLogon></AutoLogon>
            <OOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
            </OOBE>
            
            <!-- Not running? -->
            <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                   <CommandLine>powershell.exe mkdir C:\TEST\</CommandLine>
                   <Description>Open powershell</Description>
                   <Order>1</Order>
                </SynchronousCommand>
             </FirstLogonCommands>

        </component>
    </settings>
```

In the panther unattended file everything is there, except the FirstLogonCommands tag and its content. It is just simply not there.